# how to make a conclusion from the Windows screen in the application?

Tags: python, android, kotlin

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to display my desktop screen in my Kotlin application using a Python server. The Python server captures screenshots of the desktop and sends them over a socket connection to the Kotlin client, where they should be displayed in an ImageView. However, I'm encountering issues with getting the images to display correctly.

Here's the relevant code:

Server (Python):

```
import socket
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

HOST = 'localhost'  
PORT = 8080  

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            img = ImageGrab.grab()
            img_bytes = img.tobytes()
            conn.sendall(len(img_bytes).to_bytes(4, 'big') + img_bytes)
```

Client (Kotlin):

```
package com.voxadmin.windowtranslation

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.widget.ImageView
import java.io.DataInputStream
import java.net.Socket

class ImageClient(private val imageView: ImageView) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, ByteArray>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): ByteArray? {
        var socket: Socket? = null
        var dataInputStream: DataInputStream? = null

        try {
            socket = Socket("localhost", 8080)
            dataInputStream = DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())

            val imageSize = dataInputStream.readInt()

            val imageBytes = ByteArray(imageSize)
            dataInputStream.readFully(imageBytes)

            return imageBytes
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            dataInputStream?.close()
            socket?.close()
        }

        return null
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: ByteArray?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        if (result != null && result.isNotEmpty()) {
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.size)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.voxadmin.windowtranslation

import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.InputStream

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val imageBytes = ImageClient(imageView).execute().get()
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.isNotEmpty()) {
                val bitmap = byteArrayToBitmap(imageBytes)
                runOnUiThread {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun byteArrayToBitmap(byteArray: ByteArray): Bitmap
    {
        val inputStream: InputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray)
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
    }
}
```

Comment: "I'm encountering issues with getting the images to display correctly" - what are these issues? Also, are you sending from your desktop to your phone, but using `localhost` on both?

Comment: yes, my phone and PC are connected to the same network